# Ray init() is very slow

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I am new at using Ray, I find it wonderful, I had to divest from multiprocessing because it was not working optimally inside a class.
My only issue with Ray, and I don't understand it, is that for use on my laptop or even a way bigger computer (always on Windows 10), Ray init() is very slow, it takes between 10 and 15 seconds in average.

It might be the time necessary for it, I don't know, but that I would like to make sure. Or is there a way that on my laptop the initialization takes a fraction of a second?
I am used to the multiprocessing package for which there is not such a thing and the initialization of pools does not take forever like that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should ask a more specific question.

Comment: @Gael It really depends on your hw resources, but in general - ray.init() is NOT slow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, it seems to be a Windows problem. I used WSL and it did not take that time. I wonder if there is a quick fix for that but no answer so far and I am pretty sure I must not be the only one having this issue.

Comment: I notice the same issue here. 13s to run ray.init().

I noticed that import resource in worker.py fails. Not sure if it is relevant.

Then later in the code, these two lines take 5-6 seconds each.

Answer (score 0):

I notice the same issue here.
13s to run ray.init()!!!!!!!!!!!!

I noticed that import resource in worker.py fails. Not sure if it is relevant. Looks like it is a normal failure for Windows.

Then later in the code, these two lines take 5-6 seconds each.

```
    _global_node = ray.node.Node(
        ray_params,
        head=False,
        shutdown_at_exit=False,
        spawn_reaper=False,
        connect_only=True)

connect(
    _global_node,
    mode=driver_mode,
    log_to_driver=log_to_driver,
    worker=global_worker,
    driver_object_store_memory=_driver_object_store_memory,
    job_id=None,
    namespace=namespace,
    job_config=job_config)
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question, it seems more like a comment or another question. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The [Starting Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/starting-ray.html) page in the Ray docs show how to start Ray from the command line:

`ray start --head --port=6379`

Then, in your Python script(s), init Ray with:

`ray.init(address='auto')`

This way, you won't have to wait for Ray to initialize during each and every Python script execution.